# Does sendmail support chunking / BDAT?

Tags: smtp, sendmail

sendmail 8.14.x

Can someone please confirm if sendmail supports `BDAT` chunking functionality? I'm not seeing any reference to it in the bat book.  The only thing I could find online was a post to comp.mail.sendmail from 2002 indicating that it wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer describes [the latest sendmail release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail#Sendmail_8_releases) - sendmail-8.15.2 released 2015-07-03**

AFAIK [BDAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030) is not supported by sendmail. There is no trace of [BDAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030) in sendmail's [`RELEASE_NOTES`](ftp://ftp.sendmail.org/pub/sendmail/RELEASE_NOTES) file.

There is no trace of [BDAT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030) any file in sendmail's source files  so it is not even supported as FFR (For Future Release).

Comment: RFC1830 is in category experimental and obsoleted by 3030, and is also very old, I doubt anything would implement it today.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have changed links from obsoleted RFC-1830 to RFC-3030.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek just to clarify, are you indicating that `BDAT` itself is old and you personally doubt that it would be implemented?  Or just the implmentation described in RFC 1830?

Comment: @AnFi on a side note, can you elaborate on how to check sendmail source (for those of us that are not programmers)?  Is it as simple as grepping a specific directory?

Comment: In this specific case I have used: `grep BDAT * */*` and `grep -i BDAT * */*``.  **Sometimes** it is simple.

Comment: `ack` is often a better tool than `grep` for checking source codes

Comment: @Mike B  yes I was also referring to the fact that BDAT is old and I am wondering how to do you come today upon something this old. So I doubt it will be implemented yes, because if needed it would have been done already since 2000... even more so as it is not a product of an IETF working group but just the results of some discussions. What prompts you to study it today?

Comment: Like you can see on http://smtpfilter.sourceforge.net/esmtp.html it seems confined to Microsoft world. And it seems to create problems: https://adaptivethinking.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/smtp-esmtp-and-the-bdat-baddie/  . IETF discussions on mailing-list in 2003 were about a successor but I do not find any. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vaudreuil-esmtp-binary3-02 did not result in an RFC...